# Android - Force Stop Google Framework

Tags: android, frameworks, kill

I am having some problems on my C2DM connection, and to fix it I need to Force Stop "Google Services Framework".

I would like to automate it, so I have two questions.

1 - Is possible to write some Java code or terminal commands to my application reproduce:
Settings > Apps > All > Google Services Framework > Force Stop ?

(I have SU)

Just kill the process will do exactly that?

2 - What is the package name of Google Services Framework?
com.google...?

Comment: You should rethink what your doing and also consider migrate to GCM

Comment: That is not the problem... the C2DM connection of my phone is dropping if I leave it sleeping for more than 15 minutes, so I stop receiving Push notifications and Gtalk messages. To fix that I need to "restart" the Google Services Framework after editing gservices.db file. I am doing it by hand, and would like to automate to process.

Comment: Is your phone using WiFi only? Maybe you should contribute [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-gcm/Y33c9ib54jY/vmJRFv0SmKYJ) bacause your not the only one

Comment: I told everything I know about the problem there. But I'm just a user trying to solve an annoying problem, people there are pro!

Comment: you got an [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-gcm/Y33c9ib54jY/vmJRFv0SmKYJ). Post a [Bugs](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles) report for this and Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

## GSF package is com.google.android.gsf

***On adb:***

This does the trick

```
adb shell ps | grep com.google.android.gsf | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill
```

***In Java:***

I'm going out on a limb with the kill command, but shell command running code is perfecto.

```
 String killer = "ps | grep com.google.android.gsf | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill"
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
        os.writeBytes(killer+"\n");           
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
        os.flush();
```

Have fun killing GSF!

Comment: Well, I know we should leave processes to be managed by the OS, but I can't see another solution for my problem. That's the why I would like to do exactly what the system does when we press the Force Stop button, I don't know if it just kill the process or do something else.

I found: the `am force-stop com.google.android.gsf` command, is it better than just `kill "uid"`?

Comment: @Pedro I'm guessing kill is the native *nix command. am force-stop <package> seems to be an android only command. You choose.